# Gevent. Parsing the number of pages, which unknown in advance

Tags: python, parsing, asynchronous, gevent

Decided to settle in gevent while writing the parser and everything is OK with it, except for one problem: according to doc we need to know in advance how many pages we will parse

```
for i in range(1, 15):
    handlers_group.add(gevent.spawn(handler, i))
handlers_group.join()
```

In this case, the handler looks like this:

```
def handler(page_num):
    r = requests.get('sait.com?page={}'.format(page_num))
    if r.text != 'page not found':
        # data processing
```

What to do when number of paged to parse isn't known in advance? Should stop only when the answer is 'page not found'. We only know that the num of pages is usually from 15 to 50 and, in rare cases, more than one hundred (extreme limit do not know can meet and a million, but handle more than two or three hundred doesn't have any sense).

The most banal thing that comes to mind - to create queries to 300 pages:

```
for i in range(1, 300):
    handlers_group.add(gevent.spawn(handler, i))
handlers_group.join()
```

and kill a group of handlers_group from the function handler when the response from the server will be set to 'page not found'. But in this case due to the asynchronous response from page №300 (which assume not) may come faster than from №250 (which, let's say there), and we will kill processing pages before we get all the info.
Really hope to help the community in any direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global event that is set upon 404 and stop the iteration when event is_set

```
from gevent.event import Event
evt = Event()


def parsing_method():
    eventlets = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        gevent.sleep(0)
        if evt.is_set(): break
        eventlets.append(gevent.spawn(fn))
        #perform as usual

    gevent.join_all(*eventlets)
```

But, are you sure you can't know the number count ?

Comment: but in this case the requests to the network will be carried synchronously and use gevent no sense?  
we can not know the number of required queries.

Comment: Why should they be carried synchronously ? You spawn the eventlets in the "perform as usual part". You may want to store them in a list and join them upon exiting the loop.

Comment: it should slow down the program?  
I rewritete a handler function like this: http://pastebin.com/ryQ5zr9C
and run it like this: http://pastebin.com/fwm2tWva

Comment: the issue with the current solution is that it does not make concurrent requests until `join_all()` is called. (I may be mistaken but it is my understanding how gevent works)

Comment: The eventlets are started and they run concurrently. Join_all waits for the eventlets to complete execution.

Comment: I've probably already got you, forgive me for that. I have a website that I use to test, in fact, 18 pages. But we must remember, that we don't know that (about pages), so that i use for i in range(1, 50) and other just like in your answer (only replaced gevent.join_all(* eventlets) on gevent.joinall(eventlets) after interpreter's warning). But the time of executing is like 49 queries was made (not 18).

Comment: @oglu: `gevent.spawn()` starts a new greenlet but there is the only thread. To run concurrently, the event loop should multiplex them and therefore *something* should pass control to the event loop (usually it happens in "blocking" calls). It is like `asyncio.async(coro)` -- it starts  (schedules) the coroutine but it won't advance far unless the execution yields (so that `Task._step` method or similar could run): `yield from coro`.

Comment: There is only one thread, but io happens concurrently (reading from socket etc). So while an eventlet waits for an io to complete (dns resolution, downloading, etc) another one can progress. Of course they don't progress in parallel but they do progress concurrently.

Comment: @dadiwidono There is a possibility you get the error after you have spawned the eventlets. You could add a small delay (like 50/100ms) between calls so there is time to get a 404 before spawning additional requests.

Comment: @oglu: it is in agreement  with what I said in the previous comment.  *Cooperative* multitasking implies that greenlets should cooperate. If you put `while 1: pass` anywhere in the program; no other greenlet will advance. Could you provide an example that demonstrates that greenlets are run even if the main greenlet doesn't yield until `joinall()`? Here's [code example that demonstrates the opposite](https://gist.github.com/zed/1051f949c96e53f5d4db)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Indeed if nothing yields they won't run concurrently, but that's obvious from the nature of gevents. It's called "cooperative multitasking" for a reason. In the specific example as long as the code remain as is, they will run concurrently up until a point. We don't disagree actually, I am just simplifying for the specific case.

Comment: could you demonstrate that the code in your answer can execute  `break`? I don't see any evidence that my very first comment is wrong

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think I got what you say. Is the absence of blocking call in the loop that bother you ?

Comment: @oglu: the code doesn't work. Whatever `fn` is, `len(eventlets)` is always `10`.

Comment: `gevent.sleep(0)` yields control to the hub therefore it should work in simple cases.